# .net micro framework contacting WCF generates IO Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, ioexception, .net-micro-framework

I am developing an application that runs on a FEZ Spider board that communicate with a WCF hosted on my PC. I have followed [this example](https://www.ghielectronics.com/community/codeshare/entry/430), but instead of using a WCFServiceHost, I've hosted the WCF service in IIS.

The problem is that when I'm contacting the WCF service, the application always raises an IO Exception.

Here is the code of my simple Gadgeteer application that tests the WCF connection.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.SPOT;
using Microsoft.SPOT.Presentation;
using Microsoft.SPOT.Presentation.Controls;
using Microsoft.SPOT.Presentation.Media;
using Microsoft.SPOT.Presentation.Shapes;
using Microsoft.SPOT.Touch;

using Gadgeteer.Networking;
using GT = Gadgeteer;
using GTM = Gadgeteer.Modules;
using Gadgeteer.Modules.GHIElectronics;
using tempuri.org;
using schemas.datacontract.org.WcfServiceTest;
using Ws.Services.Binding;
using Ws.Services;

namespace GadgeteerClient
{
    public partial class Program
    {
        private bool networkUp = false;
        private IService1ClientProxy proxy;

        //*****
        // TODO: change this to the IP address of your machine that is running the WCF service
        //*****
        string hostRunningWCFService = "169.254.65.183";

        // This method is run when the mainboard is powered up or reset.   
        void ProgramStarted()
        {
            /*******************************************************************************************
            Modules added in the Program.gadgeteer designer view are used by typing 
            their name followed by a period, e.g.  button.  or  camera.

            Many modules generate useful events. Type +=<tab><tab> to add a handler to an event, e.g.:
                button.ButtonPressed +=<tab><tab>

            If you want to do something periodically, use a GT.Timer and handle its Tick event, e.g.:
                GT.Timer timer = new GT.Timer(1000); // every second (1000ms)
                timer.Tick +=<tab><tab>
                timer.Start();
            *******************************************************************************************/

            // Use Debug.Print to show messages in Visual Studio's "Output" window during debugging.
            Debug.Print("Program Started");

            // USE UpdateClientProxy.cmd to create the proxy classes
            ethernetJ11D.NetworkUp += ethernetJ11D_NetworkUp;
            ethernetJ11D.UseThisNetworkInterface();
            ethernetJ11D.UseStaticIP("169.254.141.168", "255.255.0.0", hostRunningWCFService);

            button.ButtonPressed += button_ButtonPressed;
        }

        void ethernetJ11D_NetworkUp(GTM.Module.NetworkModule sender, GTM.Module.NetworkModule.NetworkState state)
        {
            Debug.Print("NETWORK IS UP!");
            networkUp = true;

            proxy = new IService1ClientProxy(new WS2007HttpBinding(), new ProtocolVersion11());

            // NOTE: the endpoint needs to match the endpoint of the servicehost
            proxy.EndpointAddress = "http://" + hostRunningWCFService + "/Service1";
        }

        void button_ButtonPressed(Button sender, Button.ButtonState state)
        {
            if (!networkUp)
                return;

            button.TurnLedOn();

            try
            {
                GetData data = new GetData();
                data.value = 123;

                // call test
                string result = proxy.GetData(data).GetDataResult;
                // should print 123, IO Exception is instead generated
                Debug.Print("Received: " +  result);
                displayTE35.SimpleGraphics.DisplayText(result, Resources.GetFont(Resources.FontResources.NinaB), GT.Color.Gray, 30, 30);
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
            {
                Debug.Print("Error making WCF call");
                Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                button.TurnLedOff();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How could I solve this issue?

EDIT: 
Details about the exception are:

```
Exception was thrown: System.IO.IOException
```

There is no inner exception and the stack trace is:

```
Ws.Services.Binding.HttpTransportBindingElement::OnProcessInputMessage
Ws.Services.Binding.BindingElement::ProcessInputMessage
Ws.Services.Binding.BindingElement::ProcessInputMessage
Ws.Services.Binding.RequestChannel::ReceiveMessage
Ws.Services.Binding.RequestChannel::Request
tempuri.org.IService1ClientProxy::GetData
GadgeteerClient.Program::button_ButtonPressed
Gadgeteer.Modules.GHIElectronics.Button::OnButtonEvent
System.Reflection.MethodBase::Invoke
Gadgeteer.Program::DoOperation
Microsoft.SPOT.Dispatcher::PushFrameImpl
Microsoft.SPOT.Dispatcher::PushFrame
Microsoft.SPOT.Dispatcher::Run
Gadgeteer.Program::Run
```

Comment: please could you include full exception message.

Comment: Is there any line numbering available on the stack trace?

Comment: I am afraid, but the only other property of the exception that is not null or 0, is the m_stackTrace byte array, but I do not know if it could help to solve the issue.